# Average Function SQL

Tags: sql

For the following table, how can I show doctors with an average rating of 4?

```
DoctorUsername  Rating
DOC001          4
DOC001          3
DOC001          5
DOC002          3
DOC002          5
DOC003          3
DOC003          2
DOC004          5
DOC004          5
DOC005          3
DOC005          5
```

I understand there is an AVG function but I am getting confused since I have to select multiple doctors in one statement.

Comment: put your effort / research and edit the post

Comment: using a `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a HAVING clause with a group by. This allows you to compare an aggregate function (like average).

```
SELECT DoctorUsername FROM TABLE_NAME GROUP BY DoctorUsername HAVING AVG(Rating) = 4
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like this:

```
select DoctorUsername
from table
group by DoctorUsername
having avg(Rating) >= 4.0
```